# I don't understand where I missed async\await

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My code returns `Task<List<...>>`.
There is a type conversion error from `Task<List<...>>` to `List<...>`.

Tell me, please, where I did not finish await ?

```
    public async Task<List<DepartamentsResponse>> Handle(GetDepartmentsRequest token, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var departments = await _departmentApiClient.GetReception(token.accessToken, OdpgDepartmentType.Reception);

        var result = departments.ConvertAll(async d => new DepartamentsResponse
        {
            FederalDistrict = GetFederalDistrictCode(d.FederalRegion.DistrictCode),
            SubjectName = d.Name,
            Supervisor = GetDirector(d.Users.Where(u => u.InOdpgRole(OdpgUserRole.Director)).FirstOrDefault()),
            ContactsSupervisor =  GetContacts(d.Users.Where(u => u.InOdpgRole(OdpgUserRole.Director)).FirstOrDefault()),
            Schedule = "C 9:00 18:00",
            ReceptionContacts = await GetAddressAsync(d.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(d => d.AddressType == DepartmentAddressType.Reception), token)

        });
        return result;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetAddressAsync(DepartmentAddressDto? address, GetDepartmentsRequest token)
    {
        if (address != null)
        {
            var fullAddress = await  _fiasApiClient.GetFullAddress(token.accessToken,
                new ESOG.Fias.Api.Model.GetFullAddressRequest
                { BaseAddressId = address.FiasId, Building = address.Building, Room = address.Room });
            //var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DepartmentAddress>(fullAddress);
            return fullAddress;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

`GetFederalDistrictCode`, `GetDirector`, `GetContacts` - these methods are not asynchronous

It should just return a `List<>`, not `Task<List<>>`

Comment: `departments.ConvertAll(async d => ` - probably there.

Comment: Which line produces the error?  That's *probably* where the error is occurring...

Comment: @FranzGleichmann but if I remove the async, then it is not put before the GetAddressAsync method await. And if there isn't await .Then the Get Address Async method will return wrapped in Task (Task<string>)

Comment: @David "return result; " The typecast failed on this line only. Don't put await in it

Comment: @VadimTregubenko: What is the type of `result`?  The method is expecting to (asynchronously) return a `List<DepartamentsResponse>`.  If `result` is a `Task<List<DepartamentsResponse>>` then that suggests `departments.ConvertAll()` needs to be awaited, no?

Comment: Yes, but then the address selection method itself is underlined by the error. The option below helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `departments.ConvertAll` is returning a `List<Task<DepartamentsResponse>>`, but you want a `Task<List<DepartamentsResponse>>`.

Look at the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0) method for how you would convert a collection of `Task`s to a single `Task` that returns a collection. Then `await` that single `Task` and build your final list.